# Footer won't stretch the full width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my footer. It won't stretch to the full width and I really don't know why, it does not work just on one page from 8. This problem appeard when I've added a administration menu. Thanks for every help.

HTML:

```
<div id="administraceMenu">

<ul class="adminMenuPolozky">
<li><a href=""><img src="./obrazky/domu.png" alt="domu" id="obrazek"/> Domů</a>    </li>
<li><a href=""><img src="./obrazky/vypis.png" alt="Články" id="obrazek"/> Články</a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="./obrazky/tuzka.png" alt="tuzka" id="obrazek"/> Nový Článek</a></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="./obrazky/tuzka.png" alt="tuzka" id="obrazek"/> Pro rodiče</a></li>
<li><a href="/administrace/odhlasit"><img src="./obrazky/odhlasit.png" alt="odhlasit" id="obrazek"/> Odhlásit</a></li>
<li class="uzivatel"><img src="./obrazky/uzivatel.png" alt="uzivatel"     id="obrazek"/> Uživatel: <?=htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["uzivatel_jmeno"])?></li>

 </ul>

</div>
<footer>
<table class="patickaTabulka">
<tr>
<td class="adresa">
<p class="textAdresa">Tel:<br>E-mail: <br>Adresa: </p>
<div id="map">
</div>
</td>
<td class="programator">
<a class="skautLogoOdkaz" href="https://www.skaut.cz"><img id="skautLogo" src="./obrazky/skaut.png" width="275" height="350" /></a>
<p> Web nakódoval s <a class="srdce">&#x2764</a> <a class="odkazEda" href="" target="_blank">Eda</a></p>
</td>
<td class="facebook">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
width: 1;
background: rgb(178,178,178);
font-family: verdana;
position: relative;
margin-top: 30px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-right: 0px;
}

#administraceMenu .adminMenuPolozky {list-style: none; margin: 0 auto;}
#administraceMenu {background:rgb(220,220,220); border-radius:10px;height: 80px; width: 95%; border-style: outset; margin: 0;}
#administraceMenu .adminMenuPolozky li{position: relative; line-height: 4em;float: left;height: 75px;font-size: 20px;border-left: 2px solid rgb(203,203,203);
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
}
#administraceMenu a {text-decoration: none; color: black;display: inline-    block;padding: 1.5px 20px;}
#administraceMenu a:hover{opacity: 0.3; background: white; line-height: 4em;}
#administraceMenu .uzivatel{padding-left: 10px;}
```

Comment: The width of footer is set to 1. That is invalid and it doesn't make sense. You probably want to set it to 100% or remove it entirely (since by default the width will be 100%)

Comment: Thanks this worked. Thought width 1; is the same as width 100%; Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kodos Johnson said width 1; is invalid. Thanks [Kodos Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518200/kodos-johnson)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your footer styling to look like this? (width 100%)

```
footer {
width: 100%;
background: rgb(178,178,178);
font-family: verdana;
position: relative;
margin-top: 30px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
margin-right: 0px;
}
```